# Java Array sort by means of a comparator

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, nullpointerexception, comparator

The complete code can be found at: https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=7B7D2F11B13EF9C9!54468&authkey=!AD4fD8sGgc7oJIE

This is part of the code:

```
g_sorted = 0;
for (int l_loop = 0; l_loop < l_length; l_loop++)
{
    if (!l_IntegerArray[l_loop].equals(g_exclude))
    {
        g_tag[g_sorted] = l_loop;
        g_tosort_Integer[g_sorted] = l_IntegerArray[l_loop];
        g_sorted++;
    }
} // for (int l_loop = 0; l_loop < p_toSort; l_loop++)

Arrays.sort
(g_tag, 0, g_sorted, new Comparator<Integer>()
    {
        public int compare(Integer i1, Integer i2)
        {
            return Integer.compare(g_tosort_Integer[i1], g_tosort_Integer[i2]);
        }
    }
);
```

g_tosort_Integer, g_tag, g_tosort_Integer are 'Integer'.
g_exclude is used to exclude items which must not be part of the sort.

When no items are excluded (no item has the value equal to g_exclude or the if-statement is commented), everything works fine.

When 1 or more items are excluded I get a NullPointerException:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at TestSort$1.compare(TestSort.java:53)
at TestSort$1.compare(TestSort.java:50)
at java.util.TimSort.binarySort(TimSort.java:265)
at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:190)
at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:727)
at TestSort.<init>(TestSort.java:48)
at TestSort.main(TestSort.java:71)
```

Can someone explain this to me ? Thanks.

Comment: All your variable names are unconventional and hard to read.

Comment: Post any pertinent code here, not in a link please.

Comment: i1, i2, g_tosort_Integer, g_tosort_Integer[i1] or g_tosort_Integer[i2] could be null. Use a debugger or log statements to find out which one, and fix the bug.

Comment: ^ Precisely what @JBNizet said.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis: variable names are plain english and easy to read. I don't know what you mean by unconventional.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels: Code too long to publish here.

Comment: They don't follow java naming conventions.

Comment: @user3002711: variable and method names should begin with lower-case letters, class, interface and enum names should begin with an upper-case letter. Following these conventions makes your code much easier for experienced Java coders to parse and understand. Re, "code too long", don't post all your code here, but best to create a small compilable program that we can run and test and post that here, an [sscce](http://sscce.org). Your link shows code that can't be copied nor pasted, and links go bad over time, making it useless to future visitors with similar problems.

Comment: About 'unconventional': I'll see what I can do in the future, but I have some 40 programs to re-encode. About the 'SSCCE'-recommendations: that really is an interesting suggestion. I have the intention to remove the code, so the link will be useless, as you state, for future users. I don't understand why you can't copy/paste. I can, also when not logged on to skydrive, or in another browser.

Comment: All I can say is, if your problem has been solved, then for now the issue is moot, and there's no need to create and post the sscce. If it hasn't been solved, an sscce, is often the best way to help us help you find a decent solution. So while no one is forcing you to do this, I can strongly recommend it if your above problem is still in need of a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to solve. I kept your class "structure", but I took the liberty of changing variable names to get clearer what I was doing. You asked how to order an array not changing the order of elements, but changing a index upon it.

Here's the code.

```
    public class TestSort {

       int c_maxSort = 10000;
       Integer[] unsortedAndFiltered = new Integer[c_maxSort];
       Integer[] index = new Integer[c_maxSort];

       public TestSort() {

          Integer exclude = 0;
          int newPosition;
          int lengthOfOriginalArray;


          Integer[] originalArray = { 5, 3, 0, 2, 7, 1, 5, 6, 8, 4 };
          lengthOfOriginalArray = originalArray.length;

          System.out.print("Original: ");
          for (int i = 0; i < lengthOfOriginalArray; i++)
             System.out.print(originalArray[i] + " ");
          System.out.println(" - Length: " + lengthOfOriginalArray);

          newPosition = 0;

          for (int i = 0; i < lengthOfOriginalArray; i++) {

             if (!originalArray[i].equals(exclude)) {
                index[newPosition] = newPosition;
                unsortedAndFiltered[newPosition] = originalArray[i];
                newPosition++;
             }
          }

          System.out.println("Tags: ");
          for (int i = 0; i < newPosition; i++)
             System.out.print(index[i] + " ");
          System.out.println("");
          System.out.println("Unsorted numbers: ");
          for (int l_loop = 0; l_loop < newPosition; l_loop++)
             System.out.print(unsortedAndFiltered[l_loop] + " ");
          System.out.println("");

          int deleted = lengthOfOriginalArray - newPosition;
          Arrays.sort(index, 0, newPosition, new IndirectedComparator(unsortedAndFiltered, index));

          System.out.println("Sorted Tags: ");
          for (int i = 0; i < newPosition; i++)
             System.out.print(index[i] + " ");
          System.out.println("");
          System.out.println("Sorted Numbers: ");
          for (int i = 0; i < newPosition; i++)
             System.out.print(unsortedAndFiltered[index[i]] + " ");
          System.out.println("");

       }

       public static void main(String[] args) {
          new TestSort();
       }

    }
```

where the comparator is coded like this:

```
public class  IndirectedComparator implements Comparator<Integer> {


   private Integer[] array;
   private Integer[] index;

   public IndirectedComparator(Integer [] array, Integer[] index){
      this.array = array;

      this.index = new Integer[index.length];
      System.arraycopy(index, 0, this.index, 0, index.length);
   }

   @Override
   public int compare(Integer i1, Integer i2) {
      return Integer.compare(array[index[i1]], array[index[i2]]);
   }

}
```

This is my execution:

```
Original: 5 3 0 2 7 1 5 6 8 4  - Length: 10
Tags: 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
Unsorted numbers: 
5 3 2 7 1 5 6 8 4 
Sorted Tags: 
4 2 1 8 0 5 6 3 7 
Sorted Numbers: 
1 2 3 4 5 5 6 7 8
```

Comment: I dont think this is the problem. l_length is 10 and l_loop from 0..9 for the original array l_IntegerArray. g_tag and g_tosort_Integer use g_sorted, which will be 9 (from 0..8)

Comment: Please, just try and let me know if it solves. You pass 9 as index (since is your count), you must pass 8 (your array is now 0-8 indexed)

Comment: When I pass an 8 as toIndex I don't get the NullPointerException, but the array is not sorted correctly.
When an array has elements from 0..n, the toIndex should be n+1 (exclusive). This is so for Strings, Arrays.copyOfRange ...

Comment: The problem I'm struggling with is this:
when g_exclude = 0
- Source array 5 3 2 7 1 5 6 8 4 - no exclusions - g_sorted = 9 - g_tag and g_tosort_Integer elements from 0..8 - Works perfect
- Source array 5 3 0 2 7 1 5 6 8 4 - 1 exclusion - g_sorted = 9 - g_tag and g_tosort_Integer elements from 0..8 - NullPointerException
The content of g_sorted g_tag and g_tosort_Integer is exactly the same.
The first one works perfect, the second results in a NullPointerException,

Comment: I've already tried everything. Other parameters, debugstatements (System.out.println) ...
But the problem is still not solved.

I'm sorting array g_tag, with a comparator based on array g_tosort_Integer.
Maybe this causes the problem.

Comment: They are two different problems. You asked for nullpointer. It's what I've fixed. About sorting, I think it deserves another question. If you think my answer solved your NullPointerException problem, just mark as accepted (and upvote if you want). This is how SO works.

Comment: The problem is still not solved. Either I get the NullPointerException or the array is not sorted correctly (your suggestion to give the toIndex the value of 8). The paragraph starting with 'When I pass an 8 ...' explains why the toIndex must have the value of 9. The paragraph starting with 'The problem I'm struggling ...' gives a brief summary of the problem. At least, thank's a lot for your attention.

Comment: This solution works fine. Thank's a lot. I'm now going to study your answer, because I'd like to understand why my solution failed and your's is OK. Unfortunately, I'm not able to upvote you. I'm new to this site and my 'reputation' is too low.